# После переподключения к вай-фай перестают быть видны сайты локальной сети

Tags: apache, windows-10, apache2, веб-служба

На компьютере локально развернут апач 2.2, на нем база 1С. 
Когда телефон подключается к WIFI, сайт спокойно отображается, и с сайта выгружается мобильная база 1с. Но стоит отключиться телефону от WIFI и снова подключиться, как соединение пропадает, и даже просто по локальному ip ПК страница не открывается.
Единственное найденное решение - перезагрузка ПК, причем перезагрузка сервера не спасает. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Решение оказалось неожиданным: из-за медленного вай-фая, телефон начинал таскать данные по сотовым сетям, тем самым не находясь в локальной сети.